# Reading hyperlink target data using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, hyperlink, openpyxl

Currently I'm using pandas module in my script but I search and see that pandas can't read hyperlink target data. I found that openpyxl module can do this, however it seems openpyxl has bugs.
For example, I'm trying this code and I'm getting error.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'X.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
hl_obj = ws.cell(row=2, column=4).hyperlink.target
```

Error:
[image]

My excel file has an advantage that first column of hyperlink target cells has hyperlink name data.
To illustrate this, I'm adding pictures below(Orijinal excel file is much bigger, I deleted all rows and left only first and second in Sheet1 for simplicity.):

[image] [image]

Simply, hyperlink 'X1' in 'Sheet1' target data is 'A1:D6' in 'Sheet2'. (Note that: 'A1:A6' value in 'Sheet2' is 'X1', and 'A' column in 'Sheet2' will be always merged like this.)

For my problem, I think I can solve this problem using either 'X1' target data or 'X1' name itself in 'Sheet2'.  Since my excel file has many hyperlinks and sometimes they needs to be updated and its very time consuming, I prefer to solve problem using 'X1' name in 'Sheet2'.

So, how can I extract information of 'B2:D5' table from 'Sheet2' using 'X1' hyperlink in 'Sheet1'?

While suggesting solutions, if you add your solution code, I would be very appreciated.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.